# Manage Azure classic storage accounts using the RM mode

Tags: azure-powershell

I am only using the new RM mode with PowerShell. Although I see all the storage cmdlets, but they do not seem to work with the classic storage accounts.

If I run these two commands, no account are returned:

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName "mysubs | Select-AzureRmSubscription
Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "myrg"
```

Also....if I try this command:

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "myrg" -Name "myaccount" -Type Standard_GRS
```

It says no storage account exists. I think it is only looking for new storage accounts which I don't have any.

Is there a way to force the RM storage module to retrieve/manager classic storage accounts?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I can. So I used the following non-RM Cmdlts and it worked fine:

```
Add-AzureAccount
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscription
Set-AzureSubscription  -SubscriptionName $subscription -CurrentStorageAccountName $storageAccount
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $containerName
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $containerName | Export-Csv $csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ','
```

Comment: This no longer works in the recent version of Azure PowerShell.